# How to access the value of the Current point in a progressive line chart in Chart JS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart

I want to access the current point in a progressive line chart in Chart JS using javascript, e.g log the current value of the line on the console every one second where the total duration of the animation is 20 seconds.

Is it possible to do it with setInterval? Or is there easier method which isn't as clumsy?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "progressive chart line"?

Comment: I meant progressive line. Like the one here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/animations/progressive-line.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you can set the interval same way ChartJS do the animation. So sneak into the animation delay definition you have and add some code. Please note that we may not set exact seconds to delay the output, but we may use delay interval for each dot, because:

```
// Animation-----
const totalDuration = 10000; /* 10 seconds */
const delayBetweenPoints = totalDuration / data.length;
/* This delayBetweenPoints may be 100ms, or 33ms...
   depending on data.length */
```

Anyway you can do some calculations by yourserlf, or just expose one value for example every 100 points of chart data this way, look at bottom of the code:

```
// Animation-----
const totalDuration = 10000;
const delayBetweenPoints = totalDuration / data.length;
const previousY = (ctx) => ctx.index === 0 ? ctx.chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(100) : ctx.chart.getDatasetMeta(ctx.datasetIndex).data[ctx.index - 1].getProps(['y'], true).y;
const animation = {
    x: {
        type: 'number',
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: delayBetweenPoints,
        from: NaN, // the point is initially skipped
        delay(ctx) {
            if (ctx.type !== 'data' || ctx.xStarted) {
                return 0;
            }
            ctx.xStarted = true;
            return ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints;
        }
    },
    y: {
        type: 'number',
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: delayBetweenPoints,
        from: previousY,
        delay(ctx) {
            if (ctx.type !== 'data' || ctx.yStarted) {
                return 0;
            }
            ctx.yStarted = true;
            /* HERE we output the value of each data row and
               we use same delay between drawing the points: */
            if( ctx.index%100==0 ) setTimeout(()=>{
              console.log( ctx.raw.y );
            }, ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints);
            return ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints;
        }
    }
};
// Animation-----
```

You can check it on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/qdzmpLbx/), or below:

```js
    // Data-----
    const data = [];
    const data2 = [];
    let prev = 100;
    let prev2 = 80;
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        prev += 5 - Math.random() * 10;
        data.push({x: i, y: prev});
        prev2 += 5 - Math.random() * 10;
        data2.push({x: i, y: prev2});
    }
    // Data-----

    // Animation-----
    const totalDuration = 10000;
    const delayBetweenPoints = totalDuration / data.length;
    const previousY = (ctx) => ctx.index === 0 ? ctx.chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(100) : ctx.chart.getDatasetMeta(ctx.datasetIndex).data[ctx.index - 1].getProps(['y'], true).y;
    const animation = {
        x: {
            type: 'number',
            easing: 'linear',
            duration: delayBetweenPoints,
            from: NaN, // the point is initially skipped
            delay(ctx) {
                if (ctx.type !== 'data' || ctx.xStarted) {
                    return 0;
                }
                ctx.xStarted = true;
                return ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints;
            }
        },
        y: {
            type: 'number',
            easing: 'linear',
            duration: delayBetweenPoints,
            from: previousY,
            delay(ctx) {
                if (ctx.type !== 'data' || ctx.yStarted) {
                    return 0;
                }
                ctx.yStarted = true;
                /* HERE we output the value of each data row and
                   we use same delay between drawing the points: */
                if( ctx.index%100==0 ) setTimeout(()=>{
                  console.log( ctx.raw.y );
                }, ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints);
                return ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints;
            }
        }
    };
    // Animation-----

    // Config-----
    const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                borderColor: "#ff0000",
                borderWidth: 1,
                radius: 0,
                data: data,
            },
                {
                    borderColor: "#00FFFF",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    radius: 0,
                    data: data2,
                }]
        },
        options: {
            animation,
            interaction: {
                intersect: false
            },
            plugins: {
                legend: false
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    type: 'linear'
                }
            }
        }
    };
    // Config-----


    var myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: There's only one problem. It stops at 900th data on X axis. My request is to log 1000 times. Which means to log all the data on the line in real time, from 0 to 1000. And what changes would need to be done if I was to change the `total duration`?

Comment: @SachinJain just remove `if( ctx.index%100==0 )` before `setTimeout`. This will make 2000 `console.log(...)` - half of them for the magenta line, and the other half for the red line. Or you can populate an array, and log that to the console.